# Rails 5 - Shrine issue: "undefined method `cached_image_data' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've run into some issues when trying to allow the upload of an avatar with Shrine. I'm using Rails 5. I continually get the error, "undefined method `cached_image_data' for nil:NilClass".

I've tried restarting several times, and following along with various tutorials. As far as I can tell, I am doing everything I'm meant to. ImageUploader is set, my Photo model is set etc. I've included the relevant bits of code below.

apps/models/photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord

    include ImageUploader::Attachment.new(:image) 

end
```

apps/uploaders/image_uploader.rb
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
   plugin :processing
   plugin :versions, names: [:original, :thumb, :medium]
   plugin :delete_raw # delete processed files after uploading


process(:store) do |io, context|
    original = io.download
    pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
    size_80 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(80, 80)
    size_300 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(300, 300)
    original.close!
    # return hash of 3 sizes of the same image
    { original: io, thumb: size_80, medium: size_300 }
end
```

end

app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: profile, local: true) do |form| %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= form.label :image %>
     <%= form.hidden_field :image, value: @photo.cached_image_data %>
     <%= form.file_field :image, id: :photo_image_data %>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

app/controllers/profile_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :view_own_profile, only: [:show]

  def show
  end

   private
   def set_profile
     @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
   end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :mobile, 
  :street_address, :suburb, :postcode, :country, :mobile, :image, 
  :latitude, :longitude, :user_id)
end
```

end

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there's any other information needed.

Cheers,
Gen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `@photo` variable in the controller. If it can't be set because it doesn't exist yet you might want to call `@photo&.cached_image_data` (notice the `&`) in your form instead. This is the same as calling `@photo.nil? ? nil : @photo.cached_image_data` which checks if `@photo` is not `nil` before calling *#cached_image_data*. If `@photo` is `nil` the value of `nil` is used instead and *#cached_image_data* will never be called.

See the "safe navigation operator" section of the [2.3.0 release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/).

Comment: Thanks so much Johan! That worked perfectly. I'd never heard of the '&' being used there so that was very helpful as well.

Comment: I changed my answer a bit. I was not sure about the falsely part, so tested it real quick and it seems that it tests for `nil` only, if the variable contains `false` the method will still be executed. I also added a reference to the release notes for the safe navigation operator. The official docs still lack some documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

Though what 3lmin4t0r wrote is right in this case there is a more simple solution.

In the file apps/uploaders/image_uploader.rb you need to add the line

**plugin :cached_attachment_data**

To the list of plugins.